# Upload and Download CSV-File to Dropbox using API v2 and Python

Tags: python, csv, download, upload, dropbox

I'm relativly new into programming and i have trouble understanding the documentation for dropbox access via python.
I created an app in dropbox and got my token. I tested the connection by getting my account data.
But when it comes to accesing files I cant seem to understand the example given by dropbox.

I want to load a csv file in a python script. Then I want to manipulate some Data in the file and in the end I want to upload the new version again.

Can anyone explain ho to do it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to add a link to the dropbox API you're referencing

Comment: https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
This is the API